# Numbers: Countif with condition the content of a cell

Tags: numbers

I am struggling to come with a solution on this problem, making me wonder if the Countif function is designed to work this way, or what is wrong with my syntax at the end.

I have my first table with the data and the second where I want to count data.
In the second table I have columns with the "strings", which their appearance I want to count on my first table. 
My formulas is the following:

```
=COUNTIF(table1 :: B5:B7;"=T(C9)")
```

I have tried also

```
=COUNTIF(table1 :: B5:B7;"=C9")
```

But I am getting syntax error. Can someone give some insight ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find the syntax that works, but I was not allowed to post the answer. It should look like this:

```
=COUNTIF(Table 1 :: B2:B337;"="&T(A3))
```

Comment: Very important piece of information that is still not really documented in the Numbers help! Note, however, that (at least with Numbers 4.x) the `T()` function around the cell reference has to be omitted. It now works with: `=COUNTIF(Table 1 :: B2:B337;"="&A3))`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using wrong argument in condition part of formula - meaning that you should put there string that you are looking for not the address of the cell because Numbers thinks that you are looking for string "C9" and not value from C9.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input: I managed to find the syntax that works, but I was not allowed to post the answer. It should look like this: =COUNTIF(Table 1 :: B2:B337;"="&T(A3))

Answer (score 0):

```
simply =COUNTIF(table1 :: B5:B7; C9 )
```